# JavaScript "INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1" when doing init() on DHTMLx grid object

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I use a Joomla! plugin that takes advantage of the DHTMLxGrid library, particularly version 1.5. I have problem when opening the page that uses this DHTMLx Grid functionality, everything works fine with Firefox, however, when I open the page in Chrome (7 and 8) the browser hits an exception on line 60 of the dhtmlxgrid.js file, triggered by the initialization of the grid. I have included a few lines of code, I know this is very limited data, but this is what I was able to to put here as a summary. I hope someone encountered a similar problem. I have limited knowledge of JS, so any help is greatly appreciated.

If you need more specifics, let me know and I will try to include more data.

Thanks!

The php file:

```
function gridInit(){
    mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
    mygrid.setImagePath("http://mydomain.com//administrator/components/com_com/images/dhtmlxGrid/");
    mygrid.setHeader("ID,Start Period,End Period,Price (USD)");
    mygrid.setInitWidths("50,120,120,80");
    mygrid.setColAlign("center,center,center,center");
    mygrid.setColTypes("dyn,dhxCalendarA,dhxCalendarA,edn");
    mygrid.setDateFormat("%d/%m/%Y");
    mygrid.setColSorting("int,date,date,int");

    mygrid.init(); //...hits exception at this point
    //...
}
```

The js file:

```
//dhtmlxgrid.js...
this.hdr = document.createElement("TABLE");
this.hdr.style.border="1px solid gray";
this.hdr.cellSpacing = 0;
this.hdr.cellPadding = 0;
if ((!_isOpera)||(_OperaRv>=8.5))
this.hdr.style.tableLayout = "fixed";
this.hdr.className = "c_hdr".substr(2);
this.hdr.width = "100%";
//...
var hdrRow = this.hdr.insertRow(_isKHTML?2:1); //dhtmlxgrid.js:60 Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1
//...
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library in question but I'd suggest you need to include: the exact error message and the line (or even better block) of code inside the library which is erroring [if possible, not sure if it's open source]. Chrome tends to be _very_ picky about syntax so it's possible it's just a small mistake in the library which FF can handle but chrome can't - do you have a working Grid in Chrome elsewhere (ie try to narrow down the cause - thi particular code or any grid using this lib)?

Comment: Apologies - didn't spot the error message in the Q title :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means an index is negative or too large. The line the error happens on is adding a row to a table, but there is a test for _isKHTML... I assume that is testing for konqueror, which was the progenitor of WebKit which Chrome is based on. Anyhow, try taking out that test and doing this instead:

```
  var hdrRow = this.hdr.insertRow(1);
```

If that resolves the problem then the browser sniffing being used there is at fault, but if you don't have to support Linux running KDE then you should be fine without it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I replaced the problematic line with:

Comment: Sorry my first comment went through by accident, so:Thanks for the answer! I replaced the problematic line with:
   var hdrRow = this.hdr.insertRow(_isKHTML?1:1);
so it it will use insertRow(1) even if _isKHTML is true. Regarding your comment on Linux/KDE, I have checked and actually is_KHTML will be true also for Google Chrome on Windows as well, so the impact is larger than just Linux/KDE users. Anyways, now the grid shows up fine, so thanks again!